# Can I "export" an alias to the SHELL that invoked a script?

Tags: shell-script, alias, tcsh

I'm trying to write a utility script that defines certain aliases.
My SHELL is `tcsh` (can't change that).

I tried the following

```
#!/bin/tcsh  
alias log 'less ~/logs/log.`date '+%Y%m%d'`''
```

Then I run it like this:

```
./myscript  
log
```

The output I get is: `log: Command not found.`

Naturally if I run it like this:

```
source myscript  
log
```

Everything is fine.

Any way to do it without specifying `source ...`?

Comment: Did you put the `alias` in your `~/.cshrc` file?

Comment: @qweet - That is not my goal - I wanted something dynamic.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can't. By running your script you execute a new shell. Aliases will not be seen by the parent process.

The only way as pointed out is using `source` so that the current shell processes your script file (without starting a new process).

Comment: Thank you - that is what I thought - I'll add an alias to my .alias that will to `source myscript` - I wanted something easy that can be shared by all team members - an alias will do it.